# Laravel s3 strorage driver League \ Flysystem \ UnableToCheckDirectoryExistence

Tags: laravel, laravel-filament, digital-ocean-spaces

I'm having a problem using s3 storage driver in Laravel filament. I'm getting this exception:

```
League \ Flysystem \ UnableToCheckDirectoryExistence
Unable to check existence for: https:/spaces.link/bucket-name/posts/istockphoto-457796927-612x612.jpg
```

I'm using Digital Ocean spaces to store images. I can load this image by going to the URL just fine. Only thing I noticed, is that the protocol part in URL is missing one `/`, so instead of `https://` it's actaully `https:/`. I assume that is the reason for this erorr, but unfortunatelly, I can't find a way to fix it. Here's the setup of my code:

.env:

```
DO_SPACES_KEY=key
DO_SPACES_SECRET=secret
DO_SPACES_ENDPOINT=https://spaces.url
DO_SPACES_REGION=fra1
DO_SPACES_BUCKET=bucket.name
DO_SPACES_USE_PATH_STYLE_ENDPOINT=true
```

filesystems.php

```
's3' => [
        'driver' => 's3',
        'key' => env('DO_SPACES_KEY'),
        'secret' => env('DO_SPACES_SECRET'),
        'endpoint' => env('DO_SPACES_ENDPOINT'),
        'region' => env('DO_SPACES_REGION'),
        'bucket' => env('DO_SPACES_BUCKET'),
        'use_path_style_endpoint' => env('DO_SPACES_USE_PATH_STYLE_ENDPOINT', false),
        'throw' => false,
        'visibility' => 'public',
],
```

This is how I retrieve the image url:

```
return Storage::disk('s3')->url($featuredImage->path);
```

If I do a `dd()` of this value, I get the correct link with two `//` in the protocol. But the same exception occurs. If I comment out this value, I get no exception.

```
"https://spaces.link/bucket.name/posts/istockphoto-457796927-612x612.jpg" // app/Models/Post.php:103
```

If it is relevant in any way, I created a getter for this in the `Post.php` model, and this is where I get the mentioned exception:

```
protected function featuredImage(): Attribute{
    return Attribute::make(
        get: fn () => $this->getFeaturedImage(),
    );
}

public function getFeaturedImage(){
    $featuredImage = $this->images()->where('featured', true)->first();
    if($featuredImage){
        return Storage::disk('s3')->url($featuredImage->path);
    }

    return null;
}

public function images(){
    return $this->hasMany(PostImage::class, 'post_id');
}
```

When I remove the getter, everything work just fine.

Any help is appreciated.